# Android emulator click issue

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-studio-bumblebee

After update to Android Studio Bumblebee this issue start happening.

Seems like all clicks are long clicks (or right clicks), the menu is triggered all the time even if I click left side.

I have cleared the cache, deleted the emulator, updated the emulator, but after on or two minutes the issue starts happening. The issue is solved if I do a cold boot too, but two minutes after the issue starts again.

[image: Error GIF]

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: Same thing. Annoying as all ****

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, and after updating the Android emulator to the latest stable version (31.3.10-8807927), I have not experienced this anymore.

I did the update via Android Studio's "Check for updates".